# HTML and CSS div not hitting the top of the browser viewport

Tags: css, html

The problem: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYIAj.png) [image]

As you can see in the image above the mainContent floats just below the actual top op the browser view port, i cant make it stick to the top and stay centered at the same time.

Also a quick side question, how do i get the #mainContent, .rightContentBorder and .leftContentBorder to get their height from the #contentBox ID

```
body {
    background-image:url(img/CampusDjursland_Tourneyhjemmeside_grafik/RESTEN/BG_pattern.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
    text-align:left;    
}

li {
    text-align:left;
}

#contentBox {
    margin: 1px auto 1px auto;
    width:786px;
    height:auto;
    min-height:700px;
    max-height:none;
}

.leftContentBorder {
    width:27px;
    height:700px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(img/CampusDjursland_Tourneyhjemmeside_grafik/RESTEN/Leftside_orangebar1px.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

.rightContentBorder {
    width:27px;
    height:700px;
    float:right;
    background-image:url(img/CampusDjursland_Tourneyhjemmeside_grafik/RESTEN/Rightside_orangebar1px.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

#mainContent {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width:732px;
    height:700px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
```

The HTML

```
<body>
<div id="contentBox">
        <div class="leftContentBorder"></div>
        <div class="rightContentBorder"></div>
        <div id="mainContent">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: please also provide HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do a basic css reset like this:

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

This removes default paddings margins on all elements.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the body and html margin/padding in css?

```
html, body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0; }
```

As for getting the divs to take the height of their parent div. You can set divs to have height:100%; but that means nothing if the parent div doesn't have a set height. Your parent div has height:auto so it won't work.

Comment: Damn, there is not other way for the height?

Comment: margin: 1px auto 1px auto;
maybe its this?

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

I wouldn't really touch the parent html. If the body rule fails, best guess are different values set along the way. If all else fails you could use positioning and make it absolute. Prepare for headaches though.